# Reading the JSON File with multiple objects in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm a bit idiot in programming and Python. I know that these are a lot of explanations in previous questions about this but I carefully read all of them and I didn't find the solution.
I'm trying to read a JSON file which contains about 1 billion of data like this:

```
334465|{"color":"33ef","age":"55","gender":"m"}
334477|{"color":"3444","age":"56","gender":"f"}
334477|{"color":"3999","age":"70","gender":"m"}
```

I was trying hard to overcome that 6 digit numbers at the beginning of each line, but I dont know how can I read multiple JSON objects?
Here is my code but I can't find why it is not working?

```
import json

T =[]
s = open('simple.json', 'r')
ss = s.read()
for line in ss:
    line = ss[7:]
    T.append(json.loads(line))
s.close()
```

And the here is the error that I got:

```
ValueError: Extra Data: line 3 column 1 - line 5 column 48 (char 42 - 138)
```

Any suggestion would be very helpful for me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several problems with the logic of your code.

```
ss = s.read()
```

reads the entire file `s` into a single string. The next line

```
for line in ss:
```

iterates over each *character* in that string, one by one. So on each loop `line` is a single character. In

```
    line = ss[7:]
```

you are getting the entire file contents apart from the first 7 characters (in positions 0 through 6, inclusive) and replacing the previous content of `line` with that. And then

```
T.append(json.loads(line))
```

attempts to convert that to JSON and store the resulting object into the `T` list.

---

Here's some code that does what you want. We don't need to read the entire file into a string with `.read`, or into a list of lines with `.readlines`, we can simply put the file handle into a for loop and that will iterate over the file line by line.

We use a `with` statement to open the file, so that it will get closed automatically when we exit the `with` block, or if there's an IO error.

```
import json

table = []
with open('simple.json', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        table.append(json.loads(line[7:]))

for row in table:
    print(row)
```

**output**

```
{'color': '33ef', 'age': '55', 'gender': 'm'}
{'color': '3444', 'age': '56', 'gender': 'f'}
{'color': '3999', 'age': '70', 'gender': 'm'}
```

We can make this more compact by building the `table` list in a list comprehension:

```
import json

with open('simple.json', 'r') as f:
    table = [json.loads(line[7:]) for line in f]

for row in table:
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you use Pandas you can simply write 

`df = pd.read_json(f, lines=True)`

as per doc the `lines=True`:

> Read the file as a json object per line.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `readlines()` instead of `read()`, and wrap your JSON parsing in a try/except block. Your lines probably contain a trailing newline character and that would cause an error.

```
s = open('simple.json', 'r')
for line in s.readlines():
    try:
        j = line.split('|')[-1]
        json.loads(j)
    except ValueError:
        # You probably have bad JSON
        continue
```

Comment: `s.readlines()` reads the entire text file into memory, which is rather wasteful, especially if 'simple.json' contains about a billion lines, as the OP states. The table of extracted data is going to chew up a lot of RAM so it's a Good Idea for the script to be as frugal as possible.

Comment: I just noticed that your code doesn't actually do anything with the object created with `json.loads(j)`, it just throws it away.

Comment: I was solving the problem of parsing JSON properly. Thought it was apparent that you'd have to process that later.

Comment: Fair enough. And Raffael figured out what you meant. OTOH, SO answers are supposed to be of benefit to future readers too, not just the OP, but I guess if some future reader just blindly copies your code, they deserve all the trouble they get. :) Still, it's nice to avoid doing stuff like that in SO answers unless you clearly explain what you're doing in the accompanying text.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much! You guys are life saver!
This is the code that I eventually come up with it. I think it is the combination of all answers!

```
import json

table = []
with open('simple.json', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            j = line.split('|')[-1]
            table.append(json.loads(j))
        except ValueError:
            # You probably have bad JSON
            continue

for row in table:
    print(row)
```

Comment: 1. As I mentioned to Alex, `for line in s.readlines():` wastes time and RAM because it first reads the whole file into a list; just use `for line in s:` to iterate over the lines. 2. `.split` takes a `maxsplit` arg, so `j = line.split('|', 1)[-1]` is safer and more efficient than your version because it will stop scanning as soon as it finds the first '|' so you won't lose data if the JSON has a '|' in it.

Comment: 3. You probably should print or log a warning message in your `except` block, and get rid of that `continue`: it does nothing since you're at the end of the loop anyway. If you really don't want to log the error, then replace `continue` with `pass`, to make it clearer what your code is doing.